# pandas pivot table: How to find count for each group in Index and Column

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I am new to pivot table. I just want the count of each Age Grp by Mth. I tried

```
pivot1=pd.pivot_table(df,index=[ "Age Grp"], columns=["Mth"], values=["Age Grp"], aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique)
```

but get  `ValueError: Grouper for 'Age Grp' not 1-dimensional`

**DF**

```
 |Age Grp | Mth  | 
 | 0-4    |  1   |  
 | 5 -9   | 5    |  
 | 0-4    | 10   | 
 | 10-14  | 5  |
```

**Desired Outcome**

```
     Mth  |  1    | 5 | 10 |
 |Age Grp |                |
 | 0-4    |  1   |   0  | 1|
 | 5 -9   | 0    |   1  | 0|
 | 10-14  |  0   |   1  | 0|
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) instead of `pivot_table` with `values` and an `aggfunc` then use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to replace the `NaN` values with `0`:

```
ct_df = pd.crosstab(
    df['Age Grp'], df['Mth'],
    values=df['Age Grp'], aggfunc='nunique'
).fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

`ct_df`:

```
Mth      1   5   10
Age Grp            
0-4       1   0   1
10-14     0   1   0
5-9       0   1   0
```

Or with [`groupby nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) + [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df_us = df.groupby(
    ['Age Grp', 'Mth']
)['Age Grp'].nunique().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

`df_us`:

```
Mth      1   5   10
Age Grp            
0-4       1   0   1
10-14     0   1   0
5-9       0   1   0
```

---

Setup and imports

```
import pandas as pd  # 1.3.4

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Age Grp': ['0-4', '5-9', '0-4', '10-14'], 'Mth': [1, 5, 10, 5]
})
```

Comment: Alternative with pivot: `df.assign(val=1).pivot('Age Grp', 'Mth', 'val').fillna(0).astype(int)`

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
df.groupby(['Age Grp', 'Mth']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

`Output:`

```
Mth      1   5   10
Age Grp            
0-4       1   0   1
10-14     0   1   0
5-9       0   1   0
```